# .NET Anonymous Type used in Linq query to Data Service gives error on Select

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, wcf, npgsql

I am seeing an error show up when I write a fairly simple Linq query client side that should be working from what I have read from the other questions asked here about similar issues.

I have the following test code:

```
var result = publicCtx.Participants.Where(x => x.CompanyID == 1008)
  .Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Sequence = x.Sequence } ).ToList();
```

This code, when executed gives me the error:

```
Construction of entity type instances must use object initializer with default constructor.
```

From what I have read, a standard solution to needing parameterless constructors is to use an anonymous type, which I am using here. The data types are int? for CompanyID and Sequence, and string for ID. All of these are nullable fields in the entity model (old database is still getting converted). I am using a WCF Data Service using npgsql data provider for the entity model on the service side.

When I create a basic class to return the results, everything succeeds:

```
public class ParticipantResult
{
    public string ID;
    public int? Sequence;
}
```

with

```
var result = publicCtx.Participants.Where(x => x.CompanyID == 1008)
  .Select(x => new ParticipantResult() { ID = x.ID, Sequence = x.Sequence } )
  .ToList();
```

Edit: I've added the surrounding code for reference:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        publicCtx = ContextProvider.Public();

        // This first Linq call DOES work with its anonymous type
        var plan = publicCtx.Companies.Where(x => x.ID == 1008).Select(x => new { x.ID, x.PlanID }).FirstOrDefault().PlanID;
        // This throws the error
        var participants = publicCtx.Participants.Where(x => x.PlanID == plan).Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Sequence = x.Sequence } ).ToList();
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message);
    }

    DataContext = this;
    NotifyAll(); // just a quick and dirty PropertyChanged call
}

public static class ContextProvider
{
    public static PublicContext Public()
    {
        var pub = new Public.PublicContext(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PublicConnection"].ConnectionString));
        pub.SendingRequest2 += AuthenticateContext;
        return pub;
    }

    private static void AuthenticateContext(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
    {
        var user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
        var pw = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        var encodeStr = user + ":" + pw;
        var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encodeStr));

        e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    }
}
```

What else do I need to do to get anonymous types to work so I do not need to create classes in order to only select on a few columns for the query results?

Comment: I don't see how the first code snippet could throw the reported error. Can you show the full method? It seems to me that more things are happening before or after that snippet.

Comment: I've added the surrounding code for clarification. Thanks!